# Matlab algorithm for non-orthogonal diagonalization of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to find a basis in which the symmetric bilinear form given by the n x n symmetric matrix which has 2's along the diagonal and 1's everywhere else becomes the identity. That is, if S denotes this matrix, I need P such that

$$P^t S P = id $$

And then my basis is just the columns of P. Since S has eigenvalues 1 (with multiplicity n-1) and n+1 (with multiplicity 1), then the usual (orthogonal) diagonalization won't do. I hence need to run Hermite's algorithm using row and column operations to do this (non-orthogonal diagonalization).

I have tried for n small, and it is not clear to me how this generalises to arbitrary n. As it couldn't be hoped otherwise, computations become horrible as n grows and hence I would like to avoid them.

I was then wondering if someone can either:

A) tell me what this basis is.
B) tell me if there is an in-built matlab (or whatever software like wolfram alpha) operation which does this.
C) point me to a code which someone else might have written.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your basis, and hence $P$, can be found as follows. First find the eigenspaces of $S$. For your particular $S$, the eigenspaces are $\text{span}\{e_1 -e_2, e_1 -e_3, \ldots, e_1 - e_n\}$ and $\text{span}\{e_1 + e_2 + \ldots + e_n\}$. For each eigenspace, find an orthonormal basis via Gram-Schmidt. Then divide each vector by the square root of its eigenvalue. The resulting vectors will form an orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^n$ which if you take to be the columns of $P$ will give you $P^t S P = id$ as desired.

This works on the basis of the following facts. Since $S$ is positive-definite and symmetric, all of its eigenvalues are real and positive. Thus dividing by the square root of an eigenvalue makes sense. Moreover, again using that $S$ is symmetric, it follows that $S$ is diagonalizable, i.e. there is a basis of eigenvectors of $S$, and furthermore eigenvectors of $S$ with different eigenvalues are orthogonal. Therefore, if $v_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $P$ and $\lambda$ is its eigenvalue, then $$P^tSv_i = P^t(\lambda v_i) = \lambda P^tv_i$$ The resulting vector will have $\lambda v_j^tv_i = \lambda v_j\cdot v_i$ as its $j^{\text{th}}$ entry, which is $\lambda v_i \cdot v_i = 1$ if $j=i$ and $0$ otherwise. So $P^tSv_i = e_i$ and it follow that $P^tSP = id$.